# Can you use the Annihilation card on a Giant Skunk that someone else is fighting?

Tags: munchkin

Sometimes people will try to save the Giant Skunk for when they're level 9 to fight it to prevent people from screwing them over too much at the end. However my friends and I have debated about whether or not you can use the Annihilation card to remove the Giant Skunk card from the game after someone plays it.

> Giant Skunk: *They may not help you, backstab you, or use any cards either for or against you -- except for Wandering Monsters and monster enhancers.*
>
> Annihilation: *Play this card at any time to permanently remove any one card from the game. It does not go to the discard pile . . . put it back in the box and forget it. The target card must be in play when you use Annihilation on it. If an opponent had **just** played it, it is canceled and has no effect.*

Some people say yes, others say no, and still others say it depends on the timing. Which is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the Giant Skunk has just been played (via Kicking Down The Door or Looking For Trouble), then you may play Annihilation to cancel the Giant Skunk. At the time it's being played, it doesn't have all of its defensive text; Annihilation means *it never existed.*

Once it's in play, Annihilation won't help, because that isn't a monster enhancer or wandering monster.

So if you're going to Annihilate a Giant Skunk, be quick about it.

Source: [Steve Jackson Games Forum](http://forums.sjgames.com/showthread.php?t=51569)

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget about the tie breaker rule for Munchkin. "When in doubt, the owner of the game is right." So it depends on the opinion of the owner.

Comment: Whilst true, I don't think we should begin considering this a helpful and direct answer to the question. So the owner decides, but until then, what do we say is the case?

Comment: (or, more palpably: imagine if every Munchkin question had an answer like this.)